# Read and load images from SDcard asynchronously - fail

Tags: android, image, asynchronous

I'd like to load image which is on SDCARD in folder to imageView of my cell in listView. I've tried different solutions but each of them fails. When I load images normally as it is in every base tutorial everything works. I've observed that, my application slows down when it has to load many images. Images are taken from photo camera of device. I'd like to load each of them asynchronously to avoid UI slow reaction. I've tried to use Thread, Asynctask but each of them throws error: "Only the oryginal thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views". How to load images to avoid speed problems? SDImageLoader is a class which is possible to get from GITHUB. What I've tried is a standard code but is slows:

In a getView method in ListAdapter:

```
File imageFile = new File(Options.PATH_TO_FOLDER_PHOTOS_OF_APP + "test.png");
              String imageFileString = Options.PATH_TO_FOLDER_PHOTOS_OF_APP + "test.png";

// "test.png" is a test file. Each cell will have different name of file to load.

                    if(imageFile.exists())
                    {
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

//                      final SDImageLoader loader = new SDImageLoader(context);
//                      new SDImageLoader().load(imageFileString, image);

                        //UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image, url);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         final SDImageLoader loader = new SDImageLoader();
                        Resources resources = context.getResources();
                        int resurceId;
                        resurceId = resources.getIdentifier("bad", "drawable",context.getPackageName());
                        loader.load(imageFileString, image);

                        image.setImageResource(resurceId);
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Picasso or Glide library?

Comment: Picasso.with(context)
    .load(new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);

Comment: Use a thread and a handler that you post updates on the main thread on. Don't use libraries for things you don't know how to do yourself, you need to know exactly what you're short cutting by using the library.

Comment: I've tried Picasso library but there is still the same problem - app is crashing. In my applicationMain I set layout which loads XML with Fragments and everything to update in list is in Fragment. Please help me. What should I attach to help you look and help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to refresh your project after adding an external library to your project? It doesn't matter with the fragment. You send exact context to the List Adapter - which should be fragment.this.getActivity().

Comment: I'm not sure why it had a little problem but now it works fine. Thanks!